# Dell XPS screen flicker when temperature hit 80 degree Celsius

Tags: laptop, display

I have age old Dell XPS 15 L502x bought in 2011.
It was working fine till last month.
Now its screen flickers occasionally. Earlier flickering was very less frequent. However, now it seems to be more.
For last couple of days I have made some observation. I feel, when I put little bit more work load on it, it starts flickering.
I have CoreTemp running. Mostly when one of its core hit 80C or when most core at 75C+, it starts flickering. (When the laptop screen is flickering, the external monitor works fine.)
After [reading online](https://www.reddit.com/r/pcmasterrace/comments/6pag57/is_it_bad_to_run_maxmin_processor_state_at_100/), I reduced Processor State to 60%. Also I use it with battery removed. But still it is happening.
I also tried opening it, and cleaning it. But I was not able to fully open it as some screws werent moving at all. So
I just blowed some air and cleaned it with cloth. But still flickering is happening.
Will cooling pad with a lot fans help?
Is there any other way to fix this? Or the screen is at fault? (I have replaced screens 2-3 times in past.)
Any other suggestion?